# Avoiding duplicate instances and code duplication

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Let's say I have a type class `Convertable`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Convertable a b where
    convert :: a -> b
```

First of all, converting one type to the same type is identity:

```
instance Convertable a a where
    convert = id
```

Let's say we want to convert between integers and floats:

```
instance Convertable Int Float where
    convert = fromIntegral

instance Convertable Float Int where
    convert = round
```

So far, so good. But I would like to generalize this to include all integral typs and all RealFracs:

```
instance (Integral a, RealFrac b) => Convertable a b where
    convert = fromIntegral

instance (RealFrac a, Integral b) => Convertable a b where
    convert = round
```

GHC doesn't like this:

```
  Duplicate instance declarations:
    instance (Integral a, RealFrac b) => Convertable a b
      -- Defined at test.hs:9:10
    instance (RealFrac a, Integral b) => Convertable a b
      -- Defined at test.hs:12:10
```

Is there any nice solution to this that saves me creating m x n instances?

Comment: The problem is essentially that the compiler doesn't know that something can't be an instance of both `Integral` and `RealFrac`.

Comment: My thinking was that the behavior would be the same as with overlapping instances: as long as it's not used in an overlapping manner, it's fine. But apparently, this is not the case.

Comment: Even if it was possible, it would not be a good idea to exploit it in this manner. "Lossy" operations like `round` should always be explicit, IMO that something 50 years of C programming have well demonstrated. And more explicit than just "convert", because that's not what this is. That said... sure there are applications where you could say, such a generic conversion function is useful, and indeed there is [an established library which has gone through all that trouble of defining instance by instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/convertible-1.0.11.1). It also has the `Float -> Int`...